# For loop to calculate area under curve (no function) in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I would like to know how to calculate the area under a graph that I have a graph plotted in Origin Pro (x-axis=time in seconds, y-axis=CO2 concentration), using a raw data set. The graph does not have a function, so I know I can't use quad or any of those integral functions.

For each of the graphs, I need to calculate the total area under the curve from 60-960 seconds.

Here's some co-ordinates of the graph:

[image: Here's some co-ordinates of the graph]

As well as finding the the area under the curve from 60-960 seconds, I would also like to find the area under the same curve for a series of timings (x axis values) that I have in another data set, e.g.:

2nd Data set:

[image: 2nd Data set]

As I have many graphs to get through, it's been suggested that I use a for loop to do this. I am not very R literate, so any suggestions as of how to automate this, in a easy to understand way would greatly appreciated!

Please let me know if I've left any information out. Any other suggestions very welcome, I cannot get the first suggested answer to work.

Comment: Does this mean you want to do numeric integration? What is this "graph plotted in Origin Pro"? A smoother?

Comment: I interpreted this to mean calculating the area based on the known x and y values from a dataset outputted by the Origin Pro software.  If that's true, having a sample of about a dozen coordinates on the graph would make this easier to demonstrate.

Comment: How about the trapezoidal rule?

Comment: The `pracma` package has the `trapz` function to do this.

Comment: Hi Everyone, I've added some co-ordinates as pictures to help answer the question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple trapezoidal summation rule:

```
AUC <- function (conc, time) 
{
    auc <- 0
    for (i in 2:(length(time))) {
        auc <- auc + (time[i] - time[i - 1]) * (conc[i] + conc[i - 1])/2
    }
auc
}
```

Test it:

```
sapply(by(data=Indometh, INDICES = Subject, 
          FUN = function(x) auc(conc=x$conc, time=x$time)), as.numeric)
      1       4       2       5       6       3 
1.55375 2.24625 2.67875 1.69750 2.58375 2.59375 

library(pracma)
sapply(by(data=Indometh, INDICES = Subject, 
          FUN = function(x) trapz(x=x$time, y=x$conc)), as.numeric)
      1       4       2       5       6       3 
1.55375 2.24625 2.67875 1.69750 2.58375 2.59375
```

Comment: Some backround info on this [numerical integration technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences)

Comment: Thanks Edward, but how can I use this if it requires a function and I don't have a function for my graph? I don't understand!

Comment: You don't need a function. You just need the times (x) and measurements (y).